# I Want to load an iframe source from an input value

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, youtube

Here is my jquery

```
$(".load-link").click(function () {
    $link = $('.sermon-link').val();
    $(".embed-responsive-item").attr("src", '" + link + "');
});
```

And here is my HTML code.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Youtube Video Link</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-unlink"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="sermon_link form-control pull-right" name="sermon_link" value="$sermon_link" placeholder="https://youtu.be/pZT-FZqfxZA" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="load-link btn btn-success" type="button">Preview</button>
          </span>
  </div>
  <!-- /.input group -->
</div>
<!-- /.form group -->

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="thumbnail" style="background: url('assets/img/video_shot_placeholder.png'); background-style: cover;">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

On clicking the preview addon, the iframe src will load previewing the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually what I was looking for. I was calling the wrong ID, but I have rectified the issue.

```
$(".thumbnail").hide();
$(".load-link").click(function () {
    $(".thumbnail").slideDown();
    $link = $('.sermon_link').val().replace("https://youtu.be/", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/");
    $(".embed-responsive-item").attr("src", $link);
});
```

Comment: _I was calling the wrong id_......where i didn't found that code which refers to an **ID**.

Answer (score 3):

You have a wrong reference of var and you don't need to add quotes around it:

```
.attr("src", $link);
```

To make it more generic, you can do this:

```
$(".load-link").click(function () {
    var $link = $(this).parent().siblings('.sermon-link').val();
    $(this).closest('.form-group')
           .next('.thumbnail')
           .find(".embed-responsive-item").attr("src", $link);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = $('.sermon-link').val();
```

change to:

```
var link = $('.sermon-link').val();
```